# How many 5-card hands from a standard 52-card deck contain exactly 1 king and exactly 1 heart?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games

Is my solution correct?

There are two cases:

Case 1: (the chosen heart is not a king) So there are $3 \choose 1 $ ways to choose the king, and $12 \choose 1 $ ways to choose the heart, and then $52-12-3 \choose 3$ ways to choose rest of the three cards.

Case 2: (the chosen heart is a king) So there are $1 \choose 1$ way to choose the king (heart) card, and then since rest of the 4 cards cannot be a king nor heart, there are $52-1-12-3 \choose 4$ ways to choose the rest.

Then adding these two cases together we get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Almost.

In the first case, once you select a king and a heart that is not the king of hearts, there are $16$ cards from which you cannot select the other three cards: the four kings and the hearts, as $13 + 4 - 1 = 16$.  Therefore, you should have
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{52 - 13 - 4 + 1}{3}$$

Your second case is fine.